# I am consuming events from IBM MQ topic using Spring JMS. When I deploy application(same artefact) more than one pod it is giving following error

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

ERROR:

> Cause: JMSCC0111: WebSphere MQ classes for JMS attempted to set a pre-existing client ID on a Connection or JMSContext.

It is durable consumer. I understand that this error comes when more than one consumer tries to consume with same clientID. But my requirement is to have multiple consumers for same topic. Same events should not be consumed by both consumers.

Comment: You can create administrative subscription for the topic and provide a queue destination to receive the event publications. Then you run multiple consumers to receive events from the queue. This way an event message will be delivered to one of the consumer but not all.

Comment: As well as the queue approach Shashi mentions, JMS 2.0 supports "shared subscriptions" for just this purpose. Look for createSharedDurableConsumer in the JMS spec and setSubscriptionShared in Spring

Answer (score 1):

The code relating to the comments becomes:

```java
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myPubSubContainerFactory(SingleConnectionFactory scf) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

        scf.setClientId("ABCD");;
        factory.setConnectionFactory(scf);

        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);  // sub
        factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        factory.setSubscriptionShared(true);

        return factory;
    }
```

Note the use of `SingleConnectionFactory` to set the ClientID. If you set it on the `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` factory, you will get an error telling you to set it on `SingleConnectionFactory`.

The listener then is :

```java
    @JmsListener(destination = "${topic.value}", containerFactory = "myPubSubContainerFactory")
    public void subscribe(String message) {
       ...
    }
```